# Loading a local HTML page with embedded javascript files DotNetBrowser

Tags: javascript, html, .net, dotnetbrowser

I am looking through the samples and I have yet to come across an example of loading a local HTML file that contains embedded JavaScript inside it.  Something like, along with several others for the project on the main index.html page.

```
<script>src="angular.js"</script>
```

I am sure there must be a way to accomplish this, similar to how you could do it in CefSharp, where I got it working fairly quickly(unfortunately it was extremely memory intensive which was not going to work).

Basically I want to load the HTML file similarly to how one would do it in ASP.Net but without actually having to have a server, just read the file off the disk and load it into the DotNetBrowser along with any scripts it needs to load that are on the page.

I loaded it up and went into the debugging window and it appears to have loaded a lot of the scripts, but angular didn't load and it threw an error about chrome.app extensions not being available.

[image: from the debugger]
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is necessary to disable web security and allow file access for DotNetBrowser. This can be done via the Chromium command-line switches. The following article explains how to pass these switches to DotNetBrowser:

http://dotnetbrowser-support.teamdev.com/documentation/chromium-switches

The `--disable-web-security` and `--allow-file-access-from-files` switches will turn off the same-origin policy and allow file access from HTML.

Comment: Thanks!  I actually came across that a few hours before I read your answer, but it has fixed it and everything is working great now!